# Configure Gremlin Server to use Graphson 2.0

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I've downloaded apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.4 and trying to connect it from gremlin.net.

I'm getting an error:

`ServerError: Could not deserialize the JSON value as required. Nested exception: org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('@' (code 64))`

I think the server needs to be configured to use Graphson 2.0 as mentioned in the documentation but I couldn't find how to do so.
Any help on configuring tinkerpop gremlin server to use Graphson 2.0 will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding:
`- { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV2d0] }}        # application/json`
In conf/gremlin-server.yaml under 'serializers' section did the trick for me